# Pipe a text file to gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

From command line, I can plot part of the data of a text file as:

> echo "plot \"< cat myfile | awk '{print \$2}'\" | gnuplot -persist

I would like to make a simple bash script (mygnuplot) that allows me to do:

> cat myfile | awk '{print $2}' | mygnuplot

I have read all the thread but I still haven't figured it out. Can someone advise me.
Thanks, Jacopo

Comment: Your first command line has unbalanced double quotes. It can't possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

To read data from stdin, use the `-` special filename:

```
awk '{print $2}' < test.dat | gnuplot -persist -e "plot '-'"
```

See also `help special-filenames`.

But, in general gnuplot has itself several possiblities to select columns and rows e.g. with `using` and `every`.

Comment: it looks like the version of gnuplot I have does not recognise the -e option. ("Cannot open load file '-e' "). I currently run version 4.0

Comment: Than you can save the plot part in a script and call `gnuplot -persist file.gp`. That one-liner was only to show the working principle. Depending on your actual need, there may be more sophisticated approaches. Nevertheless you should consider updating your gnuplot version. There are some many new features :)

Comment: ok, for the time being I've saved a temp file and things work. Thanks for your help.